# Return a List of typed object via CreateSQLQuery in NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Been trying to get the following query working for a few hours now and am running out of ideas. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong. Any pointers much appreciated.

```
CalEvents = (List<CalEvent>)session.CreateSQLQuery(@"
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents
    INNER JOIN dbo.tb_calEvents
      ON (dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents.calEventID = dbo.tb_calEvents.id)
    WHERE dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents.calendarID = 'theCalID'"
)
.AddEntity(typeof(CalEvent))
.SetInt64("theCalID", cal.id);
```

Error:

> Kanpeki.NUnit.CalUserTest.Should_return_logged_in_user:
>   System.ArgumentException : Parameter theCalID does not exist as a
>   named parameter in [SELECT * FROM dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents INNER JOIN
>   dbo.tb_calEvents ON (dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents.calEventID =
>   dbo.tb_calEvents.id) WHERE dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents.calendarID =
>   'theCalID']

Answer (score 9):

```
"SELECT * FROM dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents INNER JOIN dbo.tb_calEvents ON (dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents.calEventID = dbo.tb_calEvents.id) WHERE dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents.calendarID = 'theCalID'"
```

should be

```
"SELECT * FROM dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents INNER JOIN dbo.tb_calEvents ON (dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents.calEventID = dbo.tb_calEvents.id) WHERE dbo.tb_calendar_calEvents.calendarID = :theCalID"
```

= 'theCalID' should be written as = :theCalId; :theCalId is how you use named parameters even in Native SQL Queries.

Comment: Thanks. that got me past one problem now I'm getting


System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Kanpeki.Domain.CalEvent]'.

Comment: You should be calling .List() at the end

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `query.ExecuteUpdate()` call.
Doing the `query.List()` is enough to issue the query on the session and return the result set.